# Proposed change: automatic suspension/review of users who spam

Tags: feature-request, new-users, spamming

Last night, while the mods were getting some much-needed rest, a new user started posting advertizements for a blog. The community moderation worked, with many of the posts were marked as SPAM. However, a new user is free (as far as I know) to continue posting spam.

I would like to propose that new users who had, let's say three posts marked as SPAM by the community (i.e. 5 SPAM flags) are automatically suspended pending moderator review and/or their posts are not published until they pass review (as [jippie](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/users/8627/jippie) [suggests](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2884/proposed-change-automatic-suspension-of-users-who-spam#comment6262_2884)). The moderator review of suspension/required review status might be useful if we are worried about some number of users colluding in chat to gang up on an unsuspecting new user.  Note that I am not proposing to ban the source IP: rather just suspend the user account.  Yes, the spammer can create a new account and continue defacing the site, however, this is a bit of an extra hoop the spammer has to jump through at no cost to the community, under the present proposal.

BTW, a similar question has been discussed in the post [How do we avoid spam recidivism?](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/645/how-do-we-avoid-spam-recidivism) here, however, both the problem and the solution proposed are somewhat different.

Comment: It is easier then you might think to get post banned. To my knowledge this happens easily and a constant attacker risks having his site blacklisted so even legitimate use can not improve google results.

Comment: Sorry, not suggesting to have the _site_ blacklisted, just the _user_.

Comment: Probably a combination of couple spam-flags and low rep is a good way to indicate a spammer.

Comment: Sure, but the issue I would like to address is defacement, not recognition.

Comment: And indeed once recognized redirect the user to a review queue before posts are being published.

Comment: Spam bots often don't check if their post actually appears online. Also you could of course show their post only to themselves so they have no clue it isn't showing for others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are already methods in place for Qbans/Abans.

They dont release the methods, as it would allow gaming, but a user who receives downvote/deleted questions/spam flags will be blocked from posting further until they modify their posts to have some of the previous actions reversed.

Having a pre-review step does not make sense to me, if they are spamming, lets just block them all together from posting.

Comment: Yes, you are right. If I post some links to Qbans/Abans [metase] answers in comments, will you edit them into your answer?

Comment: @angelatlarge you can or I can. I could not find a good overall post on what they are, but I may have been looking for it poorly.

Comment: I can't edit your answer on meta. Apparently no editing of other's stuff.  Maybe that's a new proposed feature change :)